# IntelliJ IDEA How do I move the testing and debug settings out of the iws file?

Tags: intellij-idea

We currently have our debug and test settings in our iws files. This means whenever we add a new debug setting to the iws file we have to commit it to subversion. This causes a lot of confusion and people tend to commit the iws file when they don't need to. We would like to move these settings out of the .iws file so we can just add it to the ignore list.

Answer (score 0):

I found that clicking the "share" button in the edit configuration window, it will move the configuration to the ipr file. The ipr file is needed anyway and wont change user settings. The share button is in the absolute top right corner of the config.

For the new project configuration, it gets moved out of the workspace.xml and into the .idea/runconfigurations folder. The only issue with this is that the whole .idea folder can't be ignored, but at least the workspace.xml file can be.

This was a long standing problem at my organization and I couldn't find the answer anywhere, so I hope this helps.